# CloudKit Catalog authentication not working, it was working till yesterday

Tags: cloudkit, catalog

I am trying to run https://cdn.apple-cloudkit.com/cloudkit-catalog/‌ Cloud Kit catalog. For this, I am doing Authentication using my apple developer account which has admin rights. However it is not doing authentication from today morning. It is giving me "Authentication Failed" error, It was working till yesterday. I also tried with another apple developer account which has Admin rights.

Please let me know anyone has any clue why it is not working ?

Thanks and Regards,
Trupti